# Ember.js/Handlebars.js bind conditional class property to {{#link-to}} helper

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to add a class to the link attribute but the class name is conditional.

```
{{#link-to "role" this classNames="isLoading:is-loading" tag="tr" }}
   <td {{ bind-attr class="isLoading:is-loading"}}>{{ name }}</td>
   <td>{{ role }}: {{ isLoading }}</td>
   <td>EDIT</td>
{{/link-to}}
```

So just like this. But somehow it doesn't work.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Based on what condition?

Comment: I am sorry. On the variable isLoading == true `classNames="isLoading:is-loading"` << i tried it like this - as proposed (and working) in `bind-attr`.

Comment: Have you tried just classBinding instead of classNames?

Comment: I just used `classBinding` instead of `classNames` and it worked, thanks. If you post it as an answer I will check it as the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use `classBinding` instead of `classNames`:

```
{{#link-to "role" this classBinding="isLoading:is-loading" tag="tr" }}
   <td {{ bind-attr class="isLoading:is-loading"}}>{{ name }}</td>
   <td>{{ role }}: {{ isLoading }}</td>
   <td>EDIT</td>
{{/link-to}}
```